# App crashed after adding editText

Tags: android

My apps crashed after i added the following to my code

```
String displayingText;
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

In button startview

```
displayingText = editText.getText().toString();
```

Can anyone guide me in this?

**Code for MainActivity :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

String displayingText;// = "abc";
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

public void StartService(View v) {

    displayingText = editText.getText().toString();

    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    mIntent.putExtra("PassToService",displayingText);
    startService(mIntent);//use to start the services
    Toast.makeText(this, "Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void StopService(View v){
    stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));//use to start the services)
    //stopService(serviceIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

**Error Log :**

> 12-12 07:52:19.674 6893-6893/tk.myessentialoils.toast5sec E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: tk.myessentialoils.toast5sec, PID: 6893
>                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{tk.myessentialoils.toast5sec/tk.myessentialoils.toast5sec.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2718)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:198)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
>                                                                                   at tk.myessentialoils.toast5sec.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:26)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1173)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2708)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: Please share the error log.

Comment: most likely a problem with the GUI implementation... all your elements should be declared inside onCreate()

Comment: you are trying to initialize a view even before setContentView() is called. That is giving an error. you have to initialize views after setContentView() is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- set `EditText` as global variable
- `findViewById` in your `onCreate` method

Try

```
String displayingText;// = "abc";
EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // find here
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
}
```

Comment: Yep, it works well. 
Other answer are good too. But, this is the shortest way to solve the problem.

Comment: You got 4 exactly same answers within a minute @Anthony.. This isn't the shortest, but it was the fastest..

Comment: Hahaha, yes, indeed, Thanks guys, You all are helpful

Comment: Enjoy coding .And you can look android document for learning more .

Comment: And you can upvote for another answer .Some answer also helpful for you.@Anthony

Comment: @Noel I didnt get your meaning of marking my question as answer, did I?
Yes, upvote is nice, but I am really asking simple question, lol
Perhaps others will downvote me after i upvote myself...haha

Comment: Nice! Yep, will do so in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText editText; // declare global variable
```

in `onCreate` Method do `findViewById`

```
editText  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Comment: If declare under onCreate, the editText inside the StartService(View v) will be unabled to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText editText;
String displayingText;// = "abc";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
}

public void StartService(View v) {

    displayingText = editText.getText().toString();

    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    mIntent.putExtra("PassToService",displayingText);
    startService(mIntent);//use to start the services
    Toast.makeText(this, "Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void StopService(View v){
    stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));//use to start the services)
    //stopService(serviceIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most Android components can't be initialised when they are declared. If you want to use them, you have to declare them as a normal field and initialise them in `onCreate`.  In the end it will look like this:

```
EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this way-:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

             initViews();
    }

    String displayingText;// = "abc";


    public void StartService(View v) {

        displayingText = editText.getText().toString();

        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        mIntent.putExtra("PassToService",displayingText);
        startService(mIntent);//use to start the services
        Toast.makeText(this, "Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void StopService(View v){
        stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));//use to start the services)
        //stopService(serviceIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   private void initViews()
   {
       EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);


   }
```

}

Declare all your views in initViews() method and specify id should be same as in .xml file.